# How to hide a column in DataGrid on Windows Mobile 6 Professional, .NET Compact Framework 3.5?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, datagrid, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Most of the solutions I could find rely on [DataGridColumn.Visibility Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.visibility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [DataGridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383893%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) both of which are not available in Windows Mobile 6 / .NET Compact Framework (to be more specific: version I'm running on my device is .NET Compact Framework 3.5.9198.0)

How can I hide a column from the DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this question just scored "popular" mark: It wasn't possible to do it by hiding the column, we've had to bypass the issue by modifying the data flow (in that case: creating a new view in t-sql) that would exclude the problematic column.

Answer (score 1):

You can and set the column style width to 0 or -1. Also you didn't mention how your setting the data in the grid. If its a datatable you can change the column mapping first before setting your datasource...

```
YOURTABLE.Columns("COLUMNID").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden
```

Comment: Isn't [ColumnMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnmapping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) used when a DataSet is saved as an XML document? Cause what you suggested doesn't seem to work and manual says just that. "_Also you didn't mention how your setting the data in the grid_" - `uxDataGrid.DataSource = MyDataSet.Tables(0)`